# UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum cannot open file Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I am creating a file path and recording to it with:

```
filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp.MOV")
videoFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
```

Then I stop recording, then

```
  let mediaLocation = (filePath).path
        if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(mediaLocation) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(mediaLocation, self, nil, nil)
        } else {
            print("Cannot find file to save")
            let player = AVPlayer(url: filePath)
            let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerController.showsPlaybackControls = true
            playerController.player = player
            present(playerController, animated: false) {
                player.play()
            }
        }
```

If i keep the media location as just `String(describing: filePath)` then the error is "cannot find the file', but the player will open the file.
If i use the above code, then the error is "cannot open", but the player will play the file.

The complete error is:

> Video
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B24F0CD8-479B-483D-AE20-0ED8040101EC/Documents/temp.MOV
>   cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error
>   Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11829 "Cannot Open"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media may be damaged.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open,
>   NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B24F0CD8-479B-483D-AE20-0ED8040101EC/Documents/temp.MOV,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x170241ef0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-12848 "(null)"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it - I added a delay before trying to save the file and it worked.  The code now reads:

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.1 // change 0.1 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(mediaLocation!) {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(mediaLocation!, self, nil, nil)
            } else {
                print("Cannot find file to save")
            }
        }
```